# Quickest way to check if a vector contains at least 1 coprime pair in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, primes, prime-factoring

I would like to write a function in MATLAB to determine whether an array contains at least one coprime pair. Formally, two integers `n` and `m` are co-prime if `gcd(m,n)==1.`

The function that I am building should input a vector `x`, and return a `true/false` value. This value will be true if `x` contains two distinct elements `n`,`m` such that `gcd(n,m)==1.` It should return false otherwise. Thus, we need it to behave as:

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
iscoprime(x)
> true
```

and

```
x = 2*[1,2,3,4];
iscoprime(x)
> false
```

My current best attempt at this is the following function.

```
function value = has_coprime_pair(x)

%take out zeros
x(x==0) = [];

%take absolute value
x = abs(x);

%make sure we have elements
if isempty(x)

    value = true;

%make sure all elements are integers
elseif any(x~=floor(x))

    value = false;

%check if any element = 1
elseif any(x==1)

    value = true;

%check if any pair of elements is coprime
else

    %get prime factors of all elements
    prime_factors   = arrayfun(@(x) factor(x), x, 'UniformOutput', false);
    all_factors     = unique(cell2mat(prime_factors));

    %remove 1 from the list of all prime factors
    all_factors(all_factors==1) = []; 

    %x does not contain coprime pair if each element has the same prime factor
    value = true;

    for f = all_factors

        can_be_factored_by_f = cellfun(@(p) any(f==p),prime_factors,'UniformOutput',true);

        if all(can_be_factored_by_f)
            value = false;
            break
        end

    end

end


end
```

Can anyone suggest a faster method?

Comment: Why not use Matlab's `gcd`? Is it slow?

Comment: "value = false; return; end" will be easier to read than "value = false;

else ... end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about correctness, you should know that your existing code fails for:

> ```
> >> has_coprime_pair([6 10 15])
>
> ans =
>
>      1
> ```

If speed is more important than correctness, you could just use

```
function value = has_coprime_pair(x)
    value = true;
end
```

To directly implement your definition:

```
value = any(any(1 == bsxfun(@gcd, x, x')))
```

Not sure about the speed, but it has the virtue of being correct:

> ```
> EDU>> has_coprime_pair([6 10 15])
>
> ans =
>
>      0
>
> EDU>> has_coprime_pair([1 2 3 4])
>
> ans =
>
>      1
>
> EDU>> has_coprime_pair(2*[1 2 3 4])
>
> ans =
>
>      0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is faster, but it's definitely simpler:

```
function result = has_coprime_pair(x)

for ii = 2:numel(x)
  result = false;  
  if any(gcd(x(ii),x(1:ii-1)) > 1) %// test each pair of nunmbers only once
    result = true;
    break
  end
end
```